# How to make ionic tab with two different function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

So i have this code for list-company.page.html

```
<div class="tab_container" [ngSwitch]="tab" *ngFor="let i of company_data">
  <ion-list lines="none" *ngSwitchCase="'list'" >
    <ion-item (click)="sendCompany(i.id)">
      <div class="item_container">
        <div class="syllabus">
          <h3>{{i.name}}</h3>
        </div>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="7">
     </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5" class="ion-text-end">
            <div class="follow">
              Follow
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

ion-list lines="none" *ngSwitchCase="'status'">
    <ion-item *ng-init='getFollowedCompany()'>
    <!-- <ion-item (click)="sendCompany(i.id)"> -->
      <div class="item_container">
        <div class="syllabus">
          
          <h3>{{i.name}}</h3>
        </div>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="7">
            <!-- <p class="d-flex">{{i.jml}} Questions  
              <span></span>
              {{i.waktu || 0}} mins
            </p> -->
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="5" class="ion-text-end">
            <div class="follow">
              Unfollow
            </div>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

So the idea is the first tab named **List** is showing a list of company from my DB with function getCompany() and to pick a company to choose

and then the second tab named **Status** is showing the company that has been choosen from the **List** tab with function getFollowedCompany()

The problem is i dont know how to set this to different function in the html page

This is the code :

**getCompany()**

```
this.api_url='https://exam.graylite.com/api/company'
await this.storage.get('email').then((val) => {
  this.email = val
});
// console.log(this.email);
var formData : FormData = new FormData();
formData.set('email',this.email);
this.http.post(this.api_url,formData)
.subscribe((response) => {
  if(response['message']=='error'){ 
    this.presentToast(response['message']);
  } else { 
    this.company_data = response['data'];
    // this.name = response['data']['name'];
    // this.company_id = response['data']['company_id'];
    console.log(this.company_data);
  }
  
});
```

**getFollowedCompany()**

```
this.api_url='https://exam.graylite.com/api/getuserapproval'
await this.storage.get('email').then((val) => {
  this.email = val
});
// console.log(this.email);
var formData : FormData = new FormData();
formData.set('email',this.email);
this.http.post(this.api_url,formData)
.subscribe((response) => {
  if(response['message']=='error'){ 
    this.presentToast(response['message']);
  } else { 
    this.company_followed = response['data'];
    // this.name = response['data']['name'];
    // this.company_id = response['data']['company_id'];
    console.log(this.company_followed);
  }
  
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question a little more please. What is meant when you say "The problem is i dont know how to set this to different function in the html page"

Comment: I dont know how to show the data in the html page